# How to change JavaScript and jQuery to Angular 4

Tags: jquery, angular

I have a code in JavaScript, it contains jQuery and uses many JS files. How to use that function in Angular 4.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/sheetjs.css">
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-3edrmyuQ0w65f8gfBsqowzjJe2iM6n0nKciPUp8y+7E="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<!--<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script> -->
<script src="assets/vendor/alertify.js"></script>
<!--<script src="//unpkg.com/canvas-datagrid/dist/canvas-datagrid.js"></script>-->


<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="assets/vendor/samples.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="assets/vendor/alertify.css">

<div id="body">
  <div id="left">   
  <div id="drop">Drop a file here</div>
  <input type="file" id="file" value=""/>
  <h3> Choose a worksheet:</h3>
  <div id="buttons"></div>
  <div id="container">
  <ul>
    <li data-jstree='{"opened":true}'>Root node

    </li>
  </ul>
</div>

<button id="STRUCT">save struct</button
<script>
$('#container').jstree({
"core" : { "check_callback" : true }, // so that operations work
"plugins" : ["dnd","contextmenu"],
"data" : function (obj, cb) {
    cb.call(this,
      ['Root 1', 'Root 2']);
}
});

  console.log('titles:');
  console.log(FIELDStitle);
  columnNames = FIELDStitle;//test

});

</script>
</div>
```

I need to implement this file functions into my Angular 4 application. I install jQuery in my application and define all needed JS file in the index, HTML file. Still, it doesn't load JS file content and gives an error. Any help?

Comment: are you using @angular/cli or a custom webpack build?

Comment: i am using @angular/cli

Comment: Show us what the error is and show us what you've done in Angular.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 solution to fix the issue.

1. Although you have added the JS file in `index.html`. But you didn't  deploy the file. So the project can't find it.

   As you are using angular/cli. You just need add the file to
   `"scripts": []` in `angular.json` or `angular-cli.json` instead of
   `index.html.`
2. In Some sulutation you can use angular grammar to replace jQuery.

   By using `renderer2` https://angular.io/api/core/Renderer2

Comment: now i think my all js file is implemented..but shows the error,                 jQuery.Deferred exception: Cannot read property '0' of undefined TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
    at HTMLDocument.eval